# Intent to open SMS app to send SMS to any selected address?

Tags: android, sms

I know since KitKat the code to start the SMS app is the following:

```
            String default_sms_package_name = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            if (default_sms_package_name != null) intent.setPackage(default_sms_package_name);
```

But is there a way to preselect the SMS receiver like the SMS body?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use ACTION_VIEW and set as many numbers as you want with address parameter as below.

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address"  , new String("0123456789;3393993300"));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body"  , "Test SMS to Angilla");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Comment: Nope, this is the pre-kitkat intent, not the intent that you need to execute since KitKat. Thanks anyway